# Conventions for naming application.properties

Tags: spring

In my Spring application, I am trying to use property-placeholder with profiles `test`,`dev`,`prod`. Also I would like to be able to load the default properties `common` which are common for all profiles.

```
<context:property-placeholder
            ignore-resource-not-found="false"
            location="classpath:application-common.properties,classpath:application-test.properties"/>
```

This however doesn't work correctly. I am not yet using the variable `${spring.profiles.active}`, because it doesn't work correctly even without it. What happens is that whatever is after the hyphen `application-` is loaded in alphabetical order. Loaded is only the first one, the other one is ignored. So in this case, only `-common` is loaded. Strange thing is, if I remove the hyphen, it load both files.

Is there some hidden behaviour I am not aware of?

Comment: How many property files you need at a time and why? think it of.

Comment: In every run I just need two - the common properties for all profiles and then properties for currently selected profile. Why is that such a bad thing to downvote?

Comment: `application.properties` is the common one... You are working around the framework instead of with the framework. Spring boot will load the `application.properties` and your `application-{profile}.properties` (and in that order). You are making things more complex by trying to out-smart the framework.

Comment: I am not using Spring boot, I am using just Spring Context. How should I describe the property-placeholder to load the application.properties and application-{profile}.properties as you are writing? I tried `classpath:application.properties,classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties` but in this case, only `application.properties` is loaded and `-test` is ignored.

Comment: Please add some info on the Spring version used.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [**@PropertySource**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) to load '**common**' property file.

   `@PropertySource({
           "classpath:application-common.properties"

   })`
2. Load environment **specific** property file by using `spring.profiles.active` while running your application.

   For example , `spring.profiles.active=dev`